# I am getting "a class, interface, or enum expected" error in blue jay

Tags: java, canvas

I am using Blue Jay and want to just create a simple rectangle. I tried adding a class to use the method Canvas but it does not seem to work. I'm getting the error "class, interface, or enum expected" on all of my opening three lines and then another error later:

```
Canvas.java:1: error: class, interface, or enum expected
java.lang.Object;
^
Canvas.java:2: error: class, interface, or enum expected
java.awt.Component;
^
Canvas.java:3: error: class, interface, or enum expected
java.awt.Canvas;
^
Canvas.java:18: error: invalid method declaration; return type required
    public test()
           ^
4 errors
```

My code is:

```
java.lang.Object;
java.awt.Component;
java.awt.Canvas;
/**
 * Write a description of class test here.
 * 
 * @author (your name) 
 * @version (a version number or a date)
 */
public class Canvas
{
    // instance variables - replace the example below with your own
    private int x;

    /**
     * Constructor for objects of class test
     */
    public test()
    {
        // initialize instance variables
        //Going to insert the code right here
    }

    /**
     * An example of a method - replace this comment with your own
     * 
     * @param  y   a sample parameter for a method
     * @return     the sum of x and y 
     */
    public int sampleMethod(int y)
    {
        // put your code here
        return x + y;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yet another homework question?

Comment: What is that invalid constructor there for? Why does your class shadow Java's Canvas? What does enum have to do with this?

Comment: @AndrewL.: Well, the `enum` part is just from the error message.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I see that, but it's not directly related at all

Comment: What are those first three lines supposed to do?

Comment: @AndrewL.: Well, quoting the error message you're getting is always directly related (and it would have been good if it had been actually quoted, verbatim, in the question).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, oh, ok. Thanks for the info :)

Comment: You should do `import java.lang.Object;`

Comment: Actually, there should never be a need to `import java.lang.Object` or anything in `java.lang` (except maybe in some obscure cases where it's needed to resolve a name conflict--but I've never seen one).

Answer (score 0):

The first three lines are missing an `import` keyword.  They should be

```
import java.lang.Object;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Canvas;
```

Also, `java.lang.Object` (and all other classes in `java.lang`) are automatically imported.  So you don't need the import on that line.  (Note: this doesn't apply to "subpackages" of `java.lang` like `java.lang.reflect`.  You don't get classes in that package automatically.)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `import` keyword before the packages that you are going to import 
For example:

`java.lang.Object;` should be  `import java.lang.Object;`